# Pop from Empty list error

Tags: python, list, debugging, stack

I am trying to push elements from a list to a stack. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Stack : 
  def __init__(self) : 
    self.items = [] 

  def push(self, item) : 
    self.items.append(item) 

  def pop(self) : 
    return self.items.pop() 

  def isEmpty(self) : 
    if self.items == []:
     return true 

def InsertIntostacks(lst1):


    X = Stack() #for each expression a stack is defined
    Y = Stack()

    for words in lst1:

      if (ord(words) >= 48  and ord(words) <= 57) or (ord(words) >=65 and ord(words) <= 90):
          X.push(words)

      else:
          Y.push(words)

    print X.pop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = open("testinput1.txt","r+")
    wordList = [line.strip() for line in a];

#print wordList[1]
    lst=list()
    for words in wordList:
      if words == '#':
       print "End of file"
      else:
          lst = list(words)
          lst1 = list()
          print lst
          for x1 in lst:
            if x1 != ' ':
             lst1.append(x1)
            InsertIntostacks(lst1)
```

So X is getting populated and I need Y to contain the operators, but apparently none of the elements are getting in Y ( input like A=B=C, so Y should contain = = ). 
If i remove the constraints and just push all the elements in one stack the operators are there. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how does the file `testinput1.txt` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect maybe your indentation is wrong for `InsertIntostacks(lst1)`, and that's the problem.

Try ensuring that `InsertIntostacks(lst1)` is properly aligned with the `for` loop, meaning it executes *after* the loop, not *within* it.  Right now it's executing during every iteration of the loop, including the first one, where `lst` is indeed empty.

Comment: It is to be inside the for loop. The lst really not empty. I have checked the code(Read: printed values) at every step, it works fine.

I suspect there is something wrong with the ASCII value for operators. When I push the elements without any if ord(words) statement, then the stack takes all the values. But as soon as a ord is encountered or even a simple check like words == '=' it fails